# convert database from latin1_swedish_ci to utf8

Tags: character-encoding

i have vBulletin database , i wont to convert it from latin1_swedish_ci to utf8_unicode_ci 
can any one know command to convert database or script or php file 
to make the charset to utf8 successfully 
Thank u

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways for this. Here is one: 
Dump the database and open that with suitable text editor and save as encoding utf8.